# regular expression to identify and extract two different strings from parent string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string: `your lead count is @_sfdc.Account.phonenumber.value, you are having  @_hrms.leaves.leavescount per year`.

From this, I want to fetch `@_sfdc.Account.phonenumber.value` and `@_hrms.leaves.leavescount`. It should fetch all dot separated stings even if we have more than one like in this case.

Currently I have tried with this regex: `/@_sfdc.([a-zA-Z]).+/g;`

Answer (score 0):

`/@_[\w\.]+/g`

This matches "@_", followed by any sequence of letters, numbers, or dots (`.`).

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right path, almost there! The main error here is that `.` is a reserved character in a regex which means "any character". To actually match a dot character, you need to escape it with a backslash: `\.`

So, your regex becomes `/@_sfdc\.([a-zA-Z])\.+/g`

Another thing to notice is that you want to match letters and dots in the same group, while your current expression requires the match to end with a dot.
So, let's move that dot inside the matching group square brackets:
`/@_sfdc\.([a-zA-Z\.])+/g`.

Also you say that you want to match both the `@_sfdc` and `@_hrms` prefixes, so let's change that.
There are two ways to do this:

- looking specifically for `@_sfdc` and `@_hrms`: `/@_(sfdc|hrms)\.([a-zA-Z\.])+/g`
- or matching any string that starts with `@_`: `/@_([a-zA-Z\.])+/g`. In this case, `hrms.` and `sfdc.` are captured by the same block that captures the rest of the string (`[a-zA-Z\.]+`)